# Retrieve escaped XML and unescape using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, escaping, xslt-1.0

I am calling a web service that embeds the response XML as escaped XML.

I'm receiving the complete SOAP response, but am only interested in the escaped XML.
I would like to get the information recived in the escaped XML and put it in some tags.

Response from the Web Service:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Body>
    <ns1:getListReturnsResponse xmlns:ns1="http://services.ws.zzz">
        <ns1:out>
            &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            &lt;returns>
                &lt;num_returns>4&lt;/num_devoluciones>
                &lt;list_returns>
                    &lt;return>
                        &lt;id_ret>111&lt;/id_ret>
                    &lt;return>
                        &lt;id_ret>222&lt;/id_ret>
                    &lt;/return>
                    &lt;return>
                        &lt;id_ret>333&lt;/id_ret>
                    &lt;/return>
                    &lt;return>
                        &lt;id_ret>444&lt;/id_ret>
                    &lt;/return>
                    &lt;/return>
                &lt;/list_returns>
            &lt;/returns>
        </ns1:out>
    </ns1:getListReturnsResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

With this response, i want to get the information in the escaped XML.

The XSLT that i'm using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://services.ws.zzz">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="//ns1:out">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        <output-parms>
            <num-returns-out><xsl:value-of select="num_returns/text()"/></num-returns-out>
        </output-parms>
</xsl:template>
```

With this, I need to have the result returned in the num_returns> tag of the XML escaped in  as here:

```
<output-parms>
    <num-returns-out>4</num-returns-out>
</output-parms>
```

Help me please!! ;)

Thanks to all

Comment: With an XSLT 1 processor to solve that in a clean way you need access to an extension function which parses the escaped input into a tree you can apply XPath to. Whether and how that works depends on the particular XSLT 1 processor and the underlying programming platform.

Comment: I added an XSLT-3.0 solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **XSLT-1.0** you have to do this in two steps:

1. Extract the escaped XML, for example with this template

   ```
   <xsl:template match="//ns1:out">
       <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
   </xsl:template>
   ```

   Notes:

   1. You cannot use `xsl:for-each` on the escaped XML like you did above.
   2. `disable-output-escaping` is not implemented by all XSLT processors, because this is optional. If it didn't work at all, this could be the reason why.
   3. Your escaped XML is not well-formed. The last `</return>` is erroneous and `num_returns` is closed with a `num_devoluciones`. There are also other errors in it, so the output must be sanitized before proceeding with step 2.
2. Transform the output again to extract the elements you want:

   ```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

     <xsl:template match="/returns">
       <output-parms>
           <num-returns-out><xsl:value-of select="num_returns/text()"/></num-returns-out>
       </output-parms>
     </xsl:template>

   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```

   **Output is:**

   ```
   <output-parms>
     <num-returns-out>4</num-returns-out>
   </output-parms>
   ```

---

If you can use an **XSLT-3.0** processor, you can make use of the XPath-3.0 [`parse-xml` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml) and achieve this in one step easily:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://services.ws.zzz">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="//ns1:out">
        <xsl:variable name="innerXML" select="parse-xml(.)" />
        <xsl:element name="output-parms">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$innerXML/returns/num_returns" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: For the initial escaping, you will need to use `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(//ns1:out)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />` - otherwise you'lll get an error along the lines of *The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it.* when attempting step 2.  (This is in addition to the error due to  mismatched tags, as noted above.)

Comment: Thank you!!
On point 3, it was a mistake to change the language to English and modify the data for the question ...